# A panel to configure JavaScript parameters on a website

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a library that would create a "settings panel" with configurable amount of sliders, checkboxes, etc and add it to a website. After a slider or checkbox is changed in the panel, a callback function would be executed.

Rationale: I am building a canvas demo and I don't want to spend time on writing my own set of controls for configurable parameters. I want to outsource this job to a small library that does it right.

I saw such thing few months ago but I cannot find it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnaly I found what I was talking about back then:

> [dat.gui](http://dataarts.github.com/dat.gui/) is a cool JavaScript ilbrary that gives you a control panel
>   for manipulating variables and calling functions in your code. It’s
>   lightweight and simple to implement – just a few lines of code.
>
> [demos](http://creativejs.com/2011/08/dat-gui/)

Answer (score 0):

[jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) provides some helpful UI elements, such as [slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/). For checkboxes you can use [event callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

Comment: jqueryui is ugly and bloated, whats wrong with `<input type='range'>`?

Comment: It only works in browsers that support it, so there needs to be a fallback if you can't guarantee which browsers will be used. You can style jQuery UI however you like, the provided themes aren't required.